# Problema con el tag base de html

Tags: html

Estoy intentando utilizar el tag base de html pero parece que no funciona y no sé por qué razón. Igual vosotros podéis ayudarme.
La he puesto en el head tal que así:

```
<base href="http://mysite.com/" /> <!--"mysite" es mi web-->
```

Tengo el archivo styles.css en el directorio principal y lo estoy llamando tal que así.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

El problema es que no se cargan los estilos y no sé por qué. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? 
Gracias de antemano

EDITO:
Esto me sale en la consola en chrome:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite.com/infantil/animales/debajo_del_mar.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://mysite.com/styles.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

EDITO: Para el que le pase lo mismo tiene que ponerlo tal que así:

```
<base href="https://mysite.com/" /> <!--"mysite" es mi web-->
```

Como veis había que poner https:// y no http://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El elemento HTML  especifica la dirección URL base que se
>   utilizará para todas las direcciones URL relativas contenidas dentro
>   de un documento. Sólo puede haber un elemento  en un documento.

Sabiendo esto, si no te funciona lo que yo haría sería usar la ruta absoluta para cargar tus **CSS** a fin de comprobar que los estás referenciando correctamente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite.com/styles.css" />
```

Si te sigue sin cargar es que no estás usando la ruta correcta donde se encuentra tu *styles.css* revísala al igual que el nombre del archivo.

No obstante te dejo un ejemplo en el que puede verse el uso de la etiqueta `<base>`. Si posicionas el puntero encima del enlace podrás ver que, aunque este tenga el atributo `href` vacío, te linkea al `<base>`. En la imagen, si la inspeccionas puede verse algo similar, que la ruta para ella está compuesta de lo que hay en `<base>` más la ruta relativa establecida en su atributo `src`.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="images/stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman">
  <a href="">HTML base Tag</a>
</body>
```

**Referencias:** [Ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), [etiqueta base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu respuesta y por ayudarme. Aún con la ruta absoluta me sigue sin aplicar los estilos. -He comprobado que esté bien escrito y si es así. No lo entiendo.

Comment: Si no te funciona ni con la absoluta es que no tienes ubicado `styles.css` en donde piensas o que no se llama `styles.css`. ¿Es posible que se llame `style.css` sin la *s*? Si pudieses adjuntar una captura del sistema de directorios que tienes en tu proyecto estaría genial. En la consola del navegador te tiene que estar apareciendo un error de que no encuentra el **css**, también estaría bien que lo adjuntases a tu pregunta.

Comment: Vale, ya localicé el problema. Estaba haciendo; <base href="http://mysite.com/" /> y había que poner https:// Edita tu respuesta con eso y te la pongo como valida por si a alguien más le pasa que pueda probar